# MS Access report opens Navigation pane when printing multiple copies via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have report I am using to print labels with and everything works fine except that when the report prints, the Navigation pane opens. I have set the database options to not show the navigation pane and other than this particular report it remains hidden. Here is the VBA I am using to print the report:

```
Dim intCopies as integer
intCopies = Me.txtCopies
DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptShippingLabelTmo", True
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , intCopies
```

The report is set up to only print to a specific printer and I need it to print multiple copies without having to use any type of dialog boxes. 
How can I get the report to print without the navigation pane opening?

Answer (score 1):

The third argument, *InNavigationPane*, indicates whether the object should be selected in the Database window (Access versions <= 2003) or Navigation pane (Access >= 2007).  Use `False` to tell Access *not* to select that report in the Navigation pane and then it shouldn't display the Navigation pane.

```vb
DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptShippingLabelTmo", False
```

However, if the report is not already open, use `OpenReport` instead of `SelectObject`, and `Close` it afterward.

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptShippingLabelTmo", acViewPreview
'DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , intCopies
DoCmd.PrintOut Copies:=intCopies
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptShippingLabelTmo"
```

Comment: thanks, I should have mentioned that I had tried using False but then I get an error saying the object is not open.

Comment: Then can you use this instead of `SelectObject`? .... `DoCmd.OpenReport "rptShippingLabelTmo", acViewPreview`

Comment: This did the trick, although I had to add a DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptShippingLabelCommercial" to get the report to close automatically. If you post as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the pane each time:

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptShippingLabelTmo", True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , intCopies
```

Comment: ,That does keep the navigation pane from opening but now I have a new issue. Instead of the report printing, I get a printout of my screenshot.

Comment: I have tried that before but that also closes the Form I have open. My users will be leaving the form open and be printing labels from it all day long so that is not a desirable result. The solution HansUp suggested with DoCmd.OpenReport actually works once I add DoCmd.Close "rptShippingLabelTmo" after the PrintOut command. Users will just have to live with seeing the report flash open and closed.

Comment: I suppose you could investigate minimizing the report. But, to me, the report flashing open is not a big deal. This is quite common behaviour in Windows and, perhaps, reassuring.